# How to complete the href in the <a> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, href

**EDIT**

I was wondering how I can complete the href from my anchor tag with Javascript.
I have the following function which gives back my longitude and latitude.

```
   function(obj){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(userPosition,errorPosition);
    }else {
        alert('Geolocation is not available');
    }
    function userPosition(position){
        obj.setAttribute('href', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?  daddr=~ITEM.STREET~,+~ITEM.CITY~&saddr=' + position.coords.latitude +  ',' position.coords.longitude);  
    }
    function errorPosition(error){
        switch(error.code){
            case eror.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert('permission denied');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I get the my current location his latitude and longitude as an alert. 
But what I want to do is the following. At the moment I have this.

```
  <a class=localization href="#" onclick="geo(this)">
                <img src="images/localizationIcon.png" width=35 height=45 />
            </a>
```

I want that when I click on the image. The longitude and latitude is filled in in my href.

Can somebody help me?

Kind regards.

Stef

Comment: are those values going to change dynamically without hitting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick="geo()"` to `onclick="geo(this)"`

Change `function geo()` to `function geo(obj)`

replace userPosition's alert with:

```
obj.setAttribute('href', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?  daddr=~ITEM.STREET~,+~ITEM.CITY~&saddr=' + position.coords.latitude +  ',' + position.coords.longitude);
```

You will have to adjust this to match Google maps format. I'm not sure what they want the address in, but I'm pretty sure you are specifying a street address in this case, not a lat/longitude combination..

Comment: You don't need to pass `this` as a parameter if the function is called with the anchor as its context. You can just reference `this` inside your function where you are using `obj`.

Comment: You do not, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Sure, but it'll make the next developer assume you don't understand scope. It's like calling `geo.call(this, this)`, which is weird.

Comment: And what should I put in the href in my anchor tag ?

Comment: Just do href="#" (or leave it out entirely). This code will set the href appropriately when the location is loaded.

Comment: @JordanMcGuigan Small typo. Your `obj.setAttribute` is missing a `+` before `position.coords.longitude`.

Comment: I'v edited my code, it is still not working. I can't click on the button.

Comment: I did in fact miss a +. What's the href evaluate to?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the whole url and just replace the whole thing.

```
var url = "google.com/maps?etc";
var newval = "google.com/maps?etc&ll"+long+","+lat;
element.href = newval;
```